# Making a smooth path from an irregular number of x,y points to simulate handwriting

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, bezier

I am trying to make a 'brush' tool in AS3 (pure, not Flex) which simulates handwriting, making strokes to be smooth instead of cornered. Then, the trace must be reduced to cubic bezier curves which can be dragged and deformed, affecting the previously drawn path (like the illustrator's pen tool).

I'm tracking the mouse movement to get a set of points to draw the path. As far as I know, I need to do a B-Spline path using that set of points. Then I should reduce it to cubic bezier curves (adding the the 'pen tool' functionality to the path).

I have already developed the pen tool, using an algorithm which reduces Cubic Beziers to Quadratic Beziers (and then using the Flash curveTo function). But I have no idea how to create a B-Spline (or another simplification), an then reduce it to Bezier curves.

Do you know any way to accomplish this?

Comment: i'm looking for the same thing but javascript, do you know any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [jhotdraw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhotdraw) is an opensource project in Java for drawing. It converts free hand drawings into cubic bezier curves. The source is available - download and translate. Don't get scared at the size of the project : you need only a couple of classes namely:

```
org.jhotdraw.geom.Bezier
org.jhotdraw.geom.BezierPath
org.jhotdraw.geom.Geom
```

While translating start by changing all the collection declarations to Arrays (use vectors if you are targeting only FP10 users). I've some regexes that you might find useful in the conversion - I can post them if you want.

---

Here is a list of regexes that you might find useful. In each pair, paste the first one into search text area and second one into replace area, check the regex check box and use Find and Replace buttons. **Don't use** `Replace All` **- none of these are guaranteed to be foolproof**.

Replace all `int/double name` declarations with `var name:Number`

```
\b(double|int)\s+(\w+)\b

var $2:Number
```

Replace all `Point2D.Double name` declarations with `var name:Point`

```
\bPoint2D\.Double\s+(\w+)\b

var $1:Point
```

Replace all `int/double name` declarations in function signatures with `name:Number`

```
\(([^)]*)\b(?:double|int)\s+(\w+)\b([^)]*?)\)

($1$2:Number$3)
```

Replace all `Point2D.Double name` declarations in function signatures with `name:Point`

```
\(([^)]*)\b(?:Point2D\.Double)\s+(\w+)\b([^)]*?)\) 

($1$2:Point$3)
```

Before changing method signatures, make sure all methods are static:

```
(public|private)\s+(?!static)
```

Replace method signatures to AS format

```
(public|private)\s+static\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)

$1 static function $3($4):$2
```

Replace ArrayList.get(index) with array[index] //Warning: fails for list.get(list.size() - 1)

```
(\w+)\.get\(([^)]+)\)

$1[$2]

//avoid the () failure 

(\w+)\.get\(([^)]*(?:\([^)]*\))[^)]*)\)

$1[$2]
```

Replace `ArrayList.set(index, element)` with `array[index] = element`
    //Warning: fails for list.set(i, list.size())

```
(\w+)\.set\(([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^)]+)\)

$1[$2] = $3


/*the above regex successfully made the following replacement*/

cleaned.set(cleaned.size() - 1, digitizedPoints[digitizedPoints.size() - 1])

cleaned[cleaned.size() - 1] = digitizedPoints[digitizedPoints.size() - 1]
```

Replace `arraylist.add(object)` with `array.push(object)`

```
//would fail if object contains ')'
//add(index, object) should be done with splice

(\w+)\.add\(([^)]+)\)

$1.push($2)

//too many failures - fail safe version - 
//still fails for nested parenthesis  list.add(new Point(a.first(), a.last())) 
//- only three such cases - the effort to match parenthesis wouldn't be worth it
//works for list.add(new Point(3, 4)) - there were many similar cases

(\w+)\.add\(([^)]*(?:\([^)]*\))[^)]*)\)

$1.push($2)
```

Replace method signatures to AS format (non static methods)

```
(public|private)\s+(?!function)(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)

$1 function $3($4):$2
```

Replace all `int/double/point/boolean name` declarations in function signatures with `name:type`

```
\(([^)]*)\b(\w+)\s+(\w+)\b([^)]*?)\)

($1$3:$2$4)
```

Replace all variable declarations in its own line with an = to AS format

```
^(\s+)(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*;(\s*)$

$1var $3:$2 = $4;$5
```

change placing of braces.

```
^(\t)(\s*)([^\n]+)\{\s*(\n)\s+

$1$2$3$4$1$2{$4$1$2
```

change `} else` into `} \n else`

```
^([ \t]+)}[ \t]*else\b([^\n]*)(\n)

$1}$3$1else$2$3
```

Replace 4 variable declarations in a single line to AS in different lines

```
^(\t+)(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*;[ \t]*(\n)

$1var $3:$2;$7$1var $4:$2;$7$1var $5:$2;$7$1var $6:$2;$7
```

Replace array declarations

```
^(\s+)\w+\[\]\s*(\w+)\b

$1 var $2:Array
```

Remove () casting - AS compiler doesn't like them

```
(?:\(\w+\)\s*)([^ ,*+;/)><=\-])

$1
```

Replace max etc into Math.max - AS doesn't have static imports

```
(?<!Math\.)\b(max|min|abs|sqrt|PI|cos|sin|atan2)\(

Math.$1(
```

Comment: I've checked the library and it looks awesome. The sample draw application does exactly what I want. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Here are the regexes I was talking about.

Comment: What an awesome work!! I have already began to port the Java code to AS3, it doesn't appear to be a difficult task, but this will speed up the process tremendously. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make sure you post the port up onto github or googlecode, I was looking for EXACTLY this, earlier today. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used this function one time.

```
    public function multicurve(g: Graphics, args: Array, closed: Boolean): void {           
            var mid: Array = args.slice();  //make dublicate
            var i: uint;
            var point: Point;
            var nextPoint: Point;
            var numPoints: uint = mid.length;

            if (numPoints == 2) {
                g.moveTo(mid[0].x, mid[0].y);
                g.lineTo(mid[1].x, mid[1].y);
                return;
            }

            var Xpoint: Array = new Array();
            var Ypoint: Array = new Array();
            for (i = 1; i < numPoints - 2; i++) {
                point = mid[i];
                nextPoint = mid[i+1];
                Xpoint[i] = 0.5*(nextPoint.x + point.x);
                Ypoint[i] = 0.5*(nextPoint.y + point.y);
            }
            if (closed) {
                Xpoint[0] = 0.5*(mid[1].x + mid[0].x);
                Ypoint[0] = 0.5*(mid[1].y + mid[0].y);
                Xpoint[i] = 0.5*(mid[i+1].x + mid[i].x);
                Ypoint[i] = 0.5*(mid[i+1].y + mid[i].y);
                Xpoint[i+1] = 0.5*(mid[i+1].x + mid[0].x);
                Ypoint[i+1] = 0.5*(mid[i+1].y + mid[0].y);
                mid.push(new Point(mid[0].x, mid[0].y));
                Xpoint[i+2] = Xpoint[0];
                Ypoint[i+2] = Ypoint[0];
            } else {
                Xpoint[0] = mid[0].x;
                Ypoint[0] = mid[0].y;
                Xpoint[i] = mid[i+1].x;
                Ypoint[i] = mid[i+1].y;
                mid.pop();
                numPoints--;
            }
            g.moveTo(Xpoint[0], Ypoint[0]);
            for (i = 1; i < numPoints; i++) {
                point = mid[i];
                g.curveTo(point.x, point.y, Xpoint[i], Ypoint[i]);
            }
            if (closed) {
                g.curveTo(mid[0].x, mid[0].y, Xpoint[i], Ypoint[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you specifically need beziers, but this catmull-rom spline tool is pretty great:
http://www.motiondraw.com/md/as_samples/t/CatmullRomSpline/tween.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm in a c library that does what you are asking:
http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gems/FitCurves.c

This is a rather complex algorithm that simplifies your geometry by converting a list of many points into a list of a few close fitting bezier curves, essentially turning scribbles into very smooth curves. It has an adjustable amount of slack, and works by finding the fewest amount of bezier curves that fit your set of points within a certain slack. So the higher you set the slack of the algorithm, the smoother (but potentially less accurate) your writing gets.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! this looks nice!. I'm already using the jHotDraw algorithm (simplified), and it works pretty much like the code you linked me. 
However, I'll take a deep look at this one too. And it seems there're more sources in the website where the file is. Thanks again for the reference!

Comment: Quick update: the FitCurves library worked, but if I did the problem over again I would approach it differently. First of all I had to tweak the library to handle fast handwriting well - fast handwriting seems to be a good way to stress test such an algorithm. More importantly though, I would make a real time algorithm that computes one curve at a time as you draw. I would keep the core part of FitCurves, which is an algorithm that returns a single curve that best fits a set of points, and customize the rest.

Comment: Link now dead. Archived here: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20090805204502/http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gems/FitCurves.c

and this looks like the new official link: 
https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/FitCurves.c

/*
An Algorithm for Automatically Fitting Digitized Curves
by Philip J. Schneider
from "Graphics Gems", Academic Press, 1990
*/